# 'Button_Click' : is not a member of 'ButtonTest::MainPage'

Tags: c++, windows, windows-store-apps

I'm new to C++ and Windows Store programming, and I'm stuck defining click handlers on buttons. I'm referring to [these](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj153345.aspx) instructions:

> 1. Add a Button control to a parent container.
> 2. To assign a name to the button, set the x:Name attribute to a string value.   To refer to a control in code, it must have a name.
>      Otherwise, a name is not required.
> 3. To assign a label to the button, set the Content property to a string value.
> 4. To perform an action when a user clicks the button, add a handler for the Click event. In the Click event handler, add code to perform
>      some action.
>
> `<Button x:Name="button1" Content="Button" 
>           Click="Button_Click" />`
>
> `void MainPage::Button_Click(Object^ sender, RoutedEventArgs^ e) {
>
>       // Add code to perform some action here.
>
>    }`

- I've added the `<Button x:Name="button1" Content="Button" Click="Button_Click" />` inside the `Grid` block in `MainPage.xaml`.
- I've added `void MainPage::Button_Click(Object^ sender, RoutedEventArgs^ e) {...}` in `MainPage.xaml.cpp`.

Now I get two errors, which I can't resolve:

> error C2039: 'Button_Click' : is not a member of 'ButtonTest::MainPage'

and

> IntelliSense: class "ButtonTest::MainPage" has no member "Button_Click"

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to define the prototype of `MainPage::Button_Click` in the `MainPage.xaml.h` file as a member of the class. Like

```
public:

    Button_Click(object^, RoutedEventArgs^);
```

C++ needs a prototype for every method.

Comment: Ah, thanks! I have added `void Button_Click(Object^ sender, RoutedEventArgs^ e);` as well as `using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml;` to the `MainPage.xaml.h` file to make it work.