# Visual basic: '<name>' is not a member of '<classname>'

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml

**Before you read, here are a couple pages I have looked at before posting this question:**

['Button_Click' : is not a member of 'ButtonTest::MainPage'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15888991/button-click-is-not-a-member-of-buttontestmainpage). This question regards C++ and is not useful as far as I am aware. According to the only answer, you need to "define the prototype of MainPage::Button_Click in the MainPage.xaml.h file as a member of the class."

[visual basic error BC30456 'Form1' is not a member of 'WindowsApplication1'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32046516/visual-basic-error-bc30456-form1-is-not-a-member-of-windowsapplication1). This question also experiences the same error, however it is caused by something else. The OP replied to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33065009/6618577), saying that it fixed the problem:

> If you have renamed the startup form1 it is likely you also have to change the Startup form setting. You can find this setting to open 'My Project' in the 'Solution Explorer'. Select the Application section, change the 'startup form' as appropriate.

In my case, I have not renamed anything since making the project, and the code which the error points to is a line which adds a handler in 'popup.g.i.vb'

I also looked on MSDN: [Creating Event Handlers for WPF Controls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb531289(v=vs.90).aspx). The page uses the following syntax to react to a button being clicked:

```
<Button Click="Button2_Click" />
```

and

```
Sub Button2_Click(ByVal Sender As Object, ByVal e As RoutedEventArgs)
    'Code here
End Sub
```

This is exactly the same syntax as I have used.

**My code**

I am currently making a program using WPF and Visual Basic, and I wanted to make a small window pop up if the user causes an error.

I have a WPF window named popup.xaml and I have a class called 'popup' which inherits from 'window'. I want to create a window and then close it when the user clicks the 'ok' button. The equivalent of this in C# would be the following:

```
popup errorWindow = new popup("Error message here");
errorWindow.ShowDialog();
```

When this method is called, an override of popup() is called which initialises and also takes the error message as a parameter.

```
public partial class popup : Window
{
    public popup()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public popup(string errorMessage)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.errorMessage.Text = errorMessage;
    }

    private void okButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

When the 'ok' button is clicked, the okButton_Click() method is called and the window closes.

In my visual basic application, I have the same WPF code for the error window:

```
<Window x:Class="FacialRecognitionVB.popup"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:FacialRecognitionVB"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Error." MinHeight="150" MaxHeight="150" Height="150" MinWidth="300" MaxWidth="300" Width="300" >
<Grid>
    <Border VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Gray" />
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="5,5,5,5" >
        <TextBlock x:Name="errorMessage" FontSize="18" FontWeight="Medium" Text="An error has occured." TextWrapping="Wrap" />
    </StackPanel>
    <Button x:Name="okButton" Template="{StaticResource ButtonTemplate}" Content="OK" Width="40" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="5,5,5,5" Click="okButton_Click" />
</Grid>
```

Despite this, the event handler for clicking the button is playing up. The VB code for my popup class is almost exactly the same:

```
Partial Public Class popup

    Inherits Window

    Public Sub Popup()
    End Sub

    Public Sub Popup(ByVal message As String)

        Dim errorMessage As TextBlock
        errorMessage.Text = message

    End Sub

    Private Sub okButton_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)

        Me.Close()

    End Sub

End Class
```

I create an instance of the class using this code in MainWindow.vb:

```
    Dim errorWindow As New popup()
    errorWindow.Popup("An error has occured.")
```

When I try to build this, I get the error *'okButton_Click' is not a member of 'popup'.* On double-clicking the error in the error list it takes me to popup.g.i.vb and highlights the following:

```
#ExternalSource ("..\..\popup.xaml", 14)
AddHandler okButton.Click, New RoutedEventHandler(AddressOf Me.okButton_Click)

#End ExternalSource
```

It will not give me any further information other than 'okButton_Click' is not a member of 'popup'

**How can I fix this?** I actually have several buttons on my main page which work perfectly using visual basic! This one button, for some reason, does not. Is there something different I need to do because it is on a separate window as part of a popup?

**Update**

I had another look round today and I found ['{name}' is not a member of '{classname}'](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6eyh1zec.aspx) on MSDN which gives the following two solution:

> 1: Check the name of the member to ensure it is accurate.
>
> 2: Use an actual member of the class.

My button is named okButton and the method is okButton_Click(). The error is highlighted in the popup.g.i.vb file, saying that Me.okButton_Click is not a member of my popup class. I do not see how either of the fixes above apply, since I *am* using the correct name and the member *does* exist.

Comment: If you are calling the popup using ShowDialog, then there should be no need to handle the OK button click, just make it the default button.  Alternatively you can still use MessageBox.show in wpf.

Comment: i use showDialog() in the C# code but not in my VB code

Comment: Is there any reason why you couldn't use either ShowDialog, or a messageBox in your VB code.

Comment: In your VB.NET code you aren't calling `InitializeComponent()`?

Comment: @DomSinclair i dont know how, i only started using visual basic today

Comment: @Mark for some reason InitializeComponent() isn't recognised? It says it is not declared

Comment: What happens if you delete that code and let the IDE re-create it by double-clicking the button?

Comment: @peterG i still get the same error

Comment: Ah, your constructors are not named correctly - in VB.NET constructors are always `Public Sub New`.  The `InitializeComponent(‌​)` call in the constructor is required for things to work correctly, but hopefully renaming the constructors will fix that issue.  Typing `Public Sub New` and pressing enter should create a method with the `InitializeComponent` call.

Comment: @Mark pressing enter after typing "Public Sub New popup()" starts a new line which is indented, but no "End Sub" statement is created, and InitialiseComponent() 'is not declared' when i type it in along with an 'End Sub' statement

Comment: Try deleting the window code and start again from the New Window menu option.

Comment: @Mark delete popup.xaml.vb and start again?

Comment: Delete popup.xaml, popup.xaml.vb and anything else (not sure if you get a designer file or not)... or just create a new window with a different name to test with.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121076/discussion-between-aric-fowler-and-mark).

Comment: Sorry, I can't access chat from work. :-(

Comment: Oh well. So i have a new window.xaml page, and window.xaml.vb

Comment: I will post the code at the bottom of the existing question

Comment: Your Window class in the xaml file seems to include the namespace.  C# includes that by default, but I'm not sure VB does.  Try making sure your class matches the actual class file:  `x:Class="popup"`

Answer (score 1):

Your constructors are not defined correctly - constructors are always named `New` in VB.NET - and you need to call `InitializeComponent` from your constructor.  You are also doing `Dim errorMessage As TextBlock`, which should not be required since it is defined in XAML.

It seems like something has broken the link between the XAML and the code behind file, and it's probably easier to delete all files related to the window and start from scratch, but your code behind should look something like this:

```vb
Partial Public Class popup
    Inherits Window

    Public Sub New()
        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(ByVal message As String)
        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()
        errorMessage.Text = message
    End Sub

    Private Sub okButton_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
        Me.Close()
    End Sub

End Class
```

In VS2015, the code behind does not have the `Partial` or `Inherits Window` parts, so those may not be required, but probably don't hurt anything.

Displaying the window should also look like the C# version:

```vb
Dim errorWindow As New popup("An error has occured.")
errorWindow.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: 'errorMessage.Text is not declared'. apart from that, both constructors work as expected and InitializeComponent() is now declared properly. I thought constructors were like in C#, where they share the name of the class.....

Comment: i tried to build and now it is saying initializeComponent() is not declared again, also the original problem 'okButton_Click() is not a member of popup' is still showing

Comment: I just deleted window.xaml since we aren't using it and that is giving me build errors too O.o

Comment: @AricFowler Are you trying to mix VB.NET and C# in the same project, or was the project originally created as C#?  Something seems to be pretty broken at the moment!

Comment: I have a reference to a C# class compiled into a .dll file, but that works perfectly... I don't have any C# code actually in the project apart from that reference since this was created as a "Visual Basic -> WPF application" project

Comment: I'm going to leave this for today and come back tomorrow. Hopefully there will be some answers overnight...